# Java proxy server which will monitor & log the traffic (HTTP, SOAP ,REST)

Tags: java, http, rest, soap, proxy

I basically want to set up a proxy server using Java which will capture the outgoing requests and the incoming response and dump it in a file.
It should be able to handle SOAP and REST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Muffin](http://muffin.doit.org/) will support these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this monitoring tool: http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-monitor/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org) (Java) --if I wasn't already using [Mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org) (NodeJS).

Answer (score 0):

**Apache JMeter** (100% Java) Open Source

Supports:

- Web - HTTP, HTTPS (Java, NodeJS, PHP, ASP.NET, …)
- SOAP / REST Webservices
- FTP
- Database via JDBC
- LDAP
- Message-oriented middleware (MOM) via JMS
- Mail - SMTP(S), POP3(S) and IMAP(S)
- Native commands or shell scripts
- TCP
- Java Objects